# replace underscores with dashes in codeigniter URL structure

Tags: php, codeigniter

im having a website which is developed using codeigniter. My URL strcuture has around 4 segments and over 500 pages. Currently my URL has underscores (_) but i need to replace it which dashes (-)

current structure

```
mywebsite.com/app/standalone_apps/high_runner_beta/download
```

required URL structure

```
mywebsite.com/app/standalone-apps/high-runner-beta/download
```

i cant user the routing feature in CI coz there are too many links that needs to be redirected.

i did try the solutions in 
[Codeigniter Routes regex - using dashes in controller/method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428134/codeigniter-routes-regex-using-dashes-in-controller-method-names)
but it didn't work.

can someone suggest a method where i can replace the underscores with dashes on my URLs.

Comment: Are you able to use .htaccess for this? If so, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2637044/844726).

Comment: as @swatkins said, .htaccess is where you need to have a look

Comment: @swatkins will try that solution.. Just to knw, what does the `$1-$2` mean?

Comment: so in your example above the `standalone_apps` is the name of the controller 
and `high_runner_beta` the name of the function 
and `download` is just an argument
, am i correct?
i want to understand your structure.

Comment: @LiveEn - the `$1` and `$2` are the captures from the regular expression.

Comment: @SportBilly `app` is the controller, `standalone_apps` is the function and `high_runner_beta`, `download are additional uri segments passed to process

Answer (score 2):

This work for me -> create a a php file: MY_Route.php
with this code and upload to 'application/core' directory:

```
<?php class MY_Router extends CI_Router { 
function set_class($class) 
{
    $this->class = str_replace('-', '_', $class);
}

function set_method($method) 
{
    $this->method = str_replace('-', '_', $method);
}

function set_directory($dir) {
    $this->directory = $dir.'/';
}

function _validate_request($segments)
{
    if (count($segments) == 0)
    {
        return $segments;
    }

    // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).'.php'))
    {
        return $segments;
    }

    // Is the controller in a sub-folder?
    if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0]))
    {
        // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
        $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
        $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);


        while(count($segments) > 0 && is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.$segments[0]))
        {
            // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
            $this->set_directory($this->directory . $segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);
        }

        if (count($segments) > 0)
        {
            // Does the requested controller exist in the sub-folder?
            if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).'.php'))
            {
                if ( ! empty($this->routes['404_override']))
                {
                    $x = explode('/', $this->routes['404_override']);

                    $this->set_directory('');
                    $this->set_class($x[0]);
                    $this->set_method(isset($x[1]) ? $x[1] : 'index');

                    return $x;
                }
                else
                {
                    show_404($this->fetch_directory().$segments[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Is the method being specified in the route?
            if (strpos($this->default_controller, '/') !== FALSE)
            {
                $x = explode('/', $this->default_controller);

                $this->set_class($x[0]);
                $this->set_method($x[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');
            }

            // Does the default controller exist in the sub-folder?
            if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.'.php'))
            {
                $this->directory = '';
                return array();
            }

        }

        return $segments;
    }


    // If we've gotten this far it means that the URI does not correlate to a valid
    // controller class.  We will now see if there is an override
    if ( ! empty($this->routes['404_override']))
    {
        $x = explode('/', $this->routes['404_override']);

        $this->set_class($x[0]);
        $this->set_method(isset($x[1]) ? $x[1] : 'index');

        return $x;
    }


    // Nothing else to do at this point but show a 404
    show_404($segments[0]);
} }
```