# redirect underscore to dash

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to .htaccess redirect:

```
http://www.site.com/projects/datasheets/batteries_data.php?file=abcd
http://www.site.com/projects/datasheets/charge_control_data.php?file=abcd
......
```

to

```
http://www.site.com/projects/datasheets/batteries-data.php?file=abcd
http://www.site.com/projects/datasheets/charge-ontrol-data.php?file=abcd
......
```

I have tried several methods like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8-$9 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: On my Motorola Defy, your code looks like a Chinese shop

Comment: But seriously, I don't remember the directive now but you might want to use a script for the conversion

Comment: Kindly use the search before posting a new question as it may have been replied like yours [**How do I use .htaccess RewriteRule to change underscores to dashes**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2637044/342740)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Prix, it worked. The problem was that I didn't knew that I have to put put it before all other rewrite rules.