# single .htaccess for multiple pages redirect with differnt url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i am changing my website and its old pages were like bellow

```
http://mydomain.com/keyword_city.html
```

while i read that its better to use - in page for batter SEO, so i am thinking to use new new page name like bellow

```
http://mydomain.com/keyword-city.html
```

first of all i want to know is this better idea to change page URL?
and if i change my URL does this effect on page ranking ?

i want to know how to write single `.htaccess` so that any request coming for old page will redirect to new URL, the only difference in old and new URL will be `_ to -`

Thanks

Comment: "change page URL" You can do that if you set up a 301 redirect to the new URL

Comment: If SEO is your only concern, i highly doubt this is going to be worth doing

Comment: For SEO you don't really need to replace `_` with `-` It won't many any difference.

Comment: Translating all `_` with `-` is not difficult with mod_rewrite but you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code added to .htacess should redirect all underscores `_` to hyphens `-`

```
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N]
```

Comment: it'll only work correctly if there's exactly one underscore (i.e. this rule will redirect `foo_bar_zum` to `foo_bar-zum`) - if appropriate a few rules will be required to cope with more underscores.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably looking for:

```
Redirect 301 /keyword_city.html /keyword-city.html
```

to be placed in your .htaccess file.

As other people have mentioned though, probably not going to help a great deal when it comes to SEO.  One thing that could however is using rich snippets/structured data:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en

Can be a lot of effort to do but would really help your presence on Google especially.

Comment: thanks and i hope so it would help but do i need to create 301 redirect for each page ? i mean there is no way to create a rule in .htaccess

Comment: If you want a generic rule to turn all underscores into hyphens that's already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637004/how-do-i-use-htaccess-rewriterule-to-change-underscores-to-dashes

That what you were after?