# Simplest solution to change the underscores of my codeigniter URLs to dashes, for SEO reasons

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have tried the following, but unfortunately it does not work:

```
$route['request-guide'] = "request_guide";
```

In my application/core I created MY_Router.php, but this is also not working.

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') || exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
        function _set_request ($seg = array())
        {
            // The str_replace() below goes through all our segments
            // and replaces the hyphens with underscores making it
            // possible to use hyphens in controllers, folder names and
            // function names
            parent::_set_request(str_replace('-', '_', $seg));
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes

Comment: this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637004/how-do-i-use-htaccess-rewriterule-to-change-underscores-to-dashes