# How to remove dots from HTTP Query using Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently my web site will try to find directory by going backwards through folders using URI constructed this way:

```
http://dummy.domain.com/home/../../section/
```

I would like to prevent this using `mod_rewrite`, but I wasn't able to write a regular expression which will be able to remove all `../` from URI. The best try was:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([\.]{2}[\/]{1})(.*)$ $1$3 [L]
```

but rule above will only remove one occurrence of `../`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes).

Comment: So you want `http://dummy.domain.com/home/../../section/` => `http://dummy.domain.com/home/section/` or something else?

Comment: Yes, and looks like it is only doable using Apache mod security to prevent directory traversal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally success to prevent directory traversal using Apache mod_security and this rule in mod_security.conf

> SecRule REQUEST_URI_RAW "\.{1,2}\/?" "log,deny,msg:'Directory
>   Traversal Attack Detected -
>   %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}:%{MATCHED_VAR}',id:123"

Comment: Also managed to achieve same thing using mod_rewrite and rules:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.{1,}\/)|(\/{2,}) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=400,L,NE]

Answer (score 1):

Your regex to match URL pattern seems to be wrong.

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:\.{2}/)+(.*)$ $1$2 [L,R,NE]

RewriteRule ^((?!home)[^/]+)/?$ /home/area/$1 [L,NC]
```

Here `\.{2}/` pattern will match `../` and `R` flag will make sure URL is redirected.

Comment: It is missing + after second group, but you helped me a lot to figure out that: ^(.*?)(\.{2}\/)+(.*?)$. Now it is matching the URI above but don't solves the problem because Apache REQUEST_URI will then be something like http://dummy.domain.com/section instead http://dummy.domain.com/home/area/section