# 301 redirect to a php redirect - bad for SEO?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

So my company has a huge website with over 7000 static pages. I have been tasked with creating a new website and attempting to account for all of the content. One way in which I've been able to do that, is by using a hash in the url to direct an AJAX call to pull content in dynamically. While this has effectively been able to eliminate many of the pages, I've been concerned with losing the site's SEO rankings, hence: redirects.

Since the new URL's have the potential to become complex (not to mention they all have a hash symbol in them), I came across one user's answer on here on how one might implement a 301 to point to a "redirector.php" and then create a php formula to point the user to the final destination. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279955/2005787)

This method has been working beautifully, however, my main concern is that by redirecting someone to a "redirector.php" file, you are losing all of your SEO rankings, since the final location is two steps removed from the original address.

So first, can I implement the "redirector.php" method without destroying my SEO rankings?

Second, if the "redirector.php" method does, in fact, hurt my rankings, then is there an alternative way to generate complicated redirects?

Thank you!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. SEO is offtopic.

Comment: How do you know you hurt your SEO rankings?

Comment: I'm referring to a discussion (on this site) that offered a programming solution to a redirect issue. To find out if that solution (from this site) is best practice to implement hardly seems off topic

Comment: I'm not sure if it has hurt my rankings yet, but I would like to know if the "redirector.php" method has the potential to ruin them

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is for programming questions. SEO is offtopic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would just have one redirect. Though Google will follow more than one and suggests 2. Maximum 3. So you could be okay with your plan.

https://youtu.be/r1lVPrYoBkA

Comment: And what's with the down votes? Stack overflow has an entire tag dedicated to SEO with almost 6000 followers, and this question was only partially about SEO and more about best practices for 301 redirects.