# htaccess rewrite rule with regular expression

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a hard time to create rewrite rule for a redirect using part of an old URL. Example:

Old URL:
http://www.example.com/news/index.php/2014/11/07/my-blog-post-from-old-site
or
http://www.example.com/news/index.php/2014/11/07/my_blog_post_from_old_site

New URL:
http://www.example.com/2014/11/07/my-blog-post

New URL should to have only dates and first three elements of a permalink after stripping from dashes. Even I'm not sure if can be done using .htaccess rule but for sure can be done using PHP.

Here are my .httaccess rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?news/index.php/.*/[^/]*?)_([^/]*?_[^/]*)$ $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(/?news/index.php/.*/[^/]*?)_([^/_]*)$ $1-$2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^news/index.php/([^/]+)-([^/]+)-(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1-$2-$3 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: What part of the URI is the same on the new link that is the same on the old link?

Comment: @PanamaJack `2014/11/07/my-blog-post`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match for the blocks until hyphen (`-`) is encountered:

```
RewriteRule ^news/index\.php/([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+).* /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: It should to have 3 blocks from dashes part - as return URI should to be something like `2014/11/07/my-blog-post`

Comment: @JackTheKnife It does. Try it first

Comment: Wow. I didn't expected that :) Learning something new on each step.

Comment: What I need to add to get `/2014/11/07/my_blog_post_from_old_site` rewrite with `2014/11/07/my-blog-post`? Looks like some URLs have underscore instead of dashes.

Comment: Replace `[^-]` with `[^_-]`

Comment: But it will put `014/11/07/my_blog_post` at the end not `014/11/07/my-blog-post` as is searching for a block which contains `-` or `_` just after index.php

Comment: @JackTheKnife You could follow this thread then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1279758/1190388

Comment: I have added rewrite rule based on a suggestion but it puts a site into infinite redirect loop when there are underscores. Check the OP for my changes.

Comment: @JackTheKnife I'd suggest asking  a new question referring to this question in that post.