# Special characters in mod_rewrite url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want this URL:

> http://www.mydomainblabla.com/games_index_files.html

to be rewritten to this one:

> http://www.mydomainblabla.com/gamesindexfiles.html

What modifications should I make to my .htaccess to make this work?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes might help you.

Comment: Not workling i only want the code